# Complete Noob Aviary SDK Implentation header import

Tags: ios, xcode, header, aviary

So I've got a basic app WireFrame going and the Nav works fine.
The app is for users to create artwork and upload for output.
I want to use the Aviary Photo Editor (with a few tweaks) to fulfill most of the artwork creation.

The major issue I'm having at the moment is understanding where to import the header to allow my app to see the `SDK`. Instruction below:

[See Point 6](http://developers.aviary.com/docs/ios/setup-guide#configuration)

My third scene is `Artworkviewcontroller` and I was trying to put it into the .h and then use:

[See basic usage](http://developers.aviary.com/docs/ios/setup-guide#configuration)

in the .m file.

BUT when I try to run the app in the simulator nothing happens! Aviary could really do with a forum!

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have have all the bits I just need to know how to bolt them all together!!

Comment: You should do the #import in your .h

Comment: Thanks John. I'd get someone to put it all together but I can't afford it! It'll be a good learning experience!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the demo application that is contained in the SDK distribution. The AFSDKDemoViewController.m file contains a full implementation of the AviarySDK. You can download the distribution here: [developers.aviary.com](http://developers.aviary.com).